# How can I protect an HTTP REST API from malicious use?

Tags: jquery, api, security, asp.net-web-api

We're developing an iPhone app along with a 3rd party. The app will request data from an ASP.NET WebAPI over HTTP. Most of the time these requests read only and have no side-effects but a couple of them allow the users to alter data or send emails. How can I protect the API from being called by users who aren't using our app?  Including a simple password seems ineffective as it could be easily sniffed by anyone with access to the app.

Is there a standard mechanism or technique to protect against problems like this?

**Edit:** Is it enough perhaps, to add a simple password to request but then use compulsory HTTPS for the API? And if using HTTPS, perhaps adding a password doesn't improve security anyway?

Comment: you need to do it in authentication/authorization of REST service.where you can get the test either user is authenticated user or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trivial solution would be to generate a random api key for each user when his account is created, it is then stocked in the app's data on connection.

Then, each request has to be signed with the api key.

It will allow you to be sure the request has been sent from a device that connected to your app, and will help you log the requests and know which user called which endpoint.

Of course, if the user is on a wifi network, he can be a victim of man in the middle and his api key can be compromised, if you're not using https.

If you don't want the api key to be "visible" in each outgoing request, you can transmit the user id and a signature that would be a concatenation of the request parameters and the api key, hashed into md5. The REST API has to do the same and check the signatures for a difference before allowing the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a heavyweight xml solution, you could setup a little internal PKI with your own CA. And issue each user a certificate (stored on their phone) then you can look into [XAdES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAdES). And create validation logic for eveloped or enveloping type signature. Either in Filter while stripping the signature before parsing or, do this manually in given method. Plus of course SSL/TLS for transport protection.